# Receiving NULL for output in program in leetcode

Tags: python

I'm working on a leetcode question in python and the question is:

Given an array of integers that is already sorted in ascending order, find two numbers such that they add up to a specific target number.

The function twoSum should return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target, where index1 must be less than index2. Please note that your returned answers (both index1 and index2) are not zero-based.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution and you may not use the same element twice.

Input: numbers={2, 7, 11, 15}, target=9
Output: index1=1, index2=2

---

The code I wrote for this question was this:

```
class Solution():
     def twoSum(self, nums, target):
         d = {}
         for i, e in enumerate(nums):
             k = target - i
             if k in d:
                 return [d[k], i]
             d[e] = i
```

But I'm receiving a NULL output and cannot figure out why

The expected answer is 
`[1,2]` 
for the example in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `k = target - e`,`i` is the index,`e` is the value,so maybe `target-e` is you want :

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    d = {}
    for i, e in enumerate(nums):
        k = target - e
        if k in d:
            return [d[k], i]
        d[e] = i


print twoSum([2,7,11,15],9)
```

Output:

```
[0,1]
```

Comment: Wow that completely flew right by me, thanks so much for catching that!